# C# не закрывает подключение к БД

Tags: c#, .net

Есть 2 формы - с первой вызывается вторая, на которой есть 2 текстовых поля. Заполняем эти поля и жмем кнопку. Должно произойти сохранение в БД и эта форма закрыться. Все работает, но коннекшн к БД продолжает висеть открытым - вижу его в процессах в мониторинге SQL Server. Закрывается только когда я полностью закрою прогу.
Код кнопки и подключения ниже:

```
 private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string connString = "Server = db02; Database = OSD_CRM_IT; Trusted_Connection = True;";
                bool result;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    string commText = "INSERT INTO ReporstGold (oldGold, newPlatinum,userLogin,dateInsert) 
VALUES (@old, @new,@usr,@date)";
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(commText, conn);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old", textBox1.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", textBox2.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", Environment.UserName);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
                    conn.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        result = true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        result = false;
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
                if (result)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Данные успешно добавлены, форма будет закрыта", "Успех");
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Добавить не удалось!");
                }
```

Вот так вижу процесс в мониторинге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект на WinForms, .NET 4.6
Должно ли закрываться подключение? Или это нормальное поведение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По умолчанию .NET использует так называемый *пул подключений* для того, чтобы повысить скорость подключения при коротких обращениях к базе.

Идея в том, что подключение не закрывается сразу, а некоторое время остаётся в открытом состоянии. Если программа попытается подключиться к базе с тем же connection string, вместо нового подключения будет задействовано существующее.

Добавьте в connection string параметр "Pooling=False", чтобы проверить. Подключение после этого должно закрываться сразу.

Подробнее о [пуле подключений](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/ado-net/net-connection-pooling).